# How to convert coordinates back to image (x,y) from hough transformation (rho, theta)?

Tags: opencv, hough-transform

I have a vector of lines produced by calling hough transformation function in Opencv, and need to convert them back to image coordinates. I found this piece of sample code from Opencv's official documentation, but I don't understand it. Would any one explain please?

```
for( size_t i = 0; i < lines->size(); i++ )
{
    float rho = lines->at(i)[0]; //[0] is rho
    float theta = lines->at(i)[1]; //[1] is theta
    double a = cos(theta), b = sin(theta);
    double x0 = a*rho, y0 = b*rho;
    cv::Point pt1(cvRound(x0 + 1000*(-b)),
              cvRound(y0 + 1000*(a)));
    cv::Point pt2(cvRound(x0 - 1000*(-b)),
              cvRound(y0 - 1000*(a)));
    line( *mat, pt1, pt2, Scalar(255,0,0), 1, 8 );
}
```

What is the 1000 doing this line?

```
pt1(cvRound(x0 + 1000*(-b)), cvRound(y0 + 1000*(a)))
```

Furthermore, why does pt2 have negative y cords?
For example, if my first line is (0,0) in (rho, theta) format, pt2 would be (0, -1000).

Thanks,

Answer (score 4):

That's how the math for normal lines works. Have a look at this article - [Converting lines from normal to slope intercept form](https://web.archive.org/web/20130617222808/http://www.aishack.in/2010/03/converting-lines-from-normal-to-slope-intercept-form/) it goes through the math.